# how to merge multiple csv files into 1 file based on column id using pandas

Tags: pandas, dataframe, csv

I have 4 CSV files with thousands of lines so I will make a quick replica of those here.

```
'zip','econ_risk_score'
'22011','5'

'zip','food_risk_score'
'22011','2'

'zip','healthlit_risk_score'
'22011','4'

'zip','housing_risk_score'
'22011','5'
```

my result table should look like this

```
'zip','econ_risk_score','food_risk_score','healthlit_risk_score','housing_risk_score'
'22011','5','2','4','5'
```

so far this is my code but I keep getting the error

```
merge() missing 1 required positional argument: 'right' and can't seem to fix it.
```

Please let me know your thoughts, thanks

```
import pandas as pd

df1= pd.read_csv('econ_risk_zip.csv')
df2= pd.read_csv('food_risk_zip.csv')
df3= pd.read_csv('health_risk_zip.csv')
df4= pd.read_csv('housing_risk_zip.csv')

df = pd.merge([df1,df2,df3,df4], right_on = 'zip')
df.to_csv('risk_combined.csv')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can merge the dataframes one by one:

```
df1= pd.read_csv('econ_risk_zip.csv', quotechar="'")
df2= pd.read_csv('food_risk_zip.csv', quotechar="'")
df3= pd.read_csv('health_risk_zip.csv', quotechar="'")
df4= pd.read_csv('housing_risk_zip.csv', quotechar="'")

df = df1.merge(df2, on="zip").merge(df3, on="zip").merge(df4, on="zip")
df.to_csv('risk_combined.csv')
```

Answer (score 3):

You can cut down on the writing with `reduce`. Just specify a list of files then you can merge them, this way if you need to add files you only need to modify the list of files.

```
from functools import reduce
import pandas as pd

files = ['econ_risk_zip.csv', 'food_risk_zip.csv',
         'health_risk_zip.csv', 'housing_risk_zip.csv']

df = reduce(lambda l,r: l.merge(r, on='zip'), [pd.read_csv(f) for f in files])
```